# Is the homotopy type of an analytified variety independent of embedding into C (with a cocyle condition)?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology, complex-geometry

I am reading *Hodge Cycles, Motives, and Shimura Varieties* by Deligne, Milne, Ogus, and Shih. On page 16, in describing some of the basic setup of Hodge theory, Deligne (or maybe Milne? The actual authorship of the chapter is presented in a confusing way) writes the following:

> For an arbitrary $k$ and embedding $\sigma:k\hookrightarrow\mathbb{C}$ we write $H^n_\sigma(X)$ for $H^n_B(\sigma X)$ and $H_\sigma^{p,q}(X)$ for $H^{p,q}(\sigma X)$. As $\iota$ defines a homeomorphism $\sigma X^{\mathrm{an}}\to\iota\sigma X^{\mathrm{an}}$, it induces an isomorphism $H^n_{\iota\sigma}(X)\to H^n_{\sigma}(X)$.

For context, here $H^n_B(X)$ means $H^n\left(X^{\mathrm{an}},\mathbb{Q}\right)$ for a complex variety $X$. As far as I can tell, he is essentially trying to assert the following:

> Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero and size $\le\mathfrak{c}$. Pick two embeddings $\sigma,\tau:k\hookrightarrow\mathbb{C}$ and an automorphism $\iota:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ satisfying $\tau=\iota\sigma$. If $X$ is a $k$-variety, then $\iota$ gives a homeomorphism $X\times_\sigma\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{C}\to X\times_\tau\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{C}$ in the analytic topology.

I interpret the action of $\iota$ to mean: act coordinatewise if $X\subseteq\mathbb{A}^n_k$ is affine, and glue for general $X$. This interpretation is evidently false: the action of $\iota$ will usually be horrifically discontinuous.

The following statement, however, is what's really necessary to give a well-defined singular cohomology theory (putting aside functoriality for brevity):

> Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero and size $\le\mathfrak{c}$. If $X$ is a $k$-variety, then to any pair of embeddings $\sigma,\tau:k\hookrightarrow\mathbb{C}$ we can associate a homotopy class of homotopy equivalences $\varphi_{\sigma,\tau}:X\times_\sigma\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{C}\to X\times_\tau\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{C}$ (analytic topologies) satisfying the cocyle conditions $\varphi_{\sigma,\upsilon}=\varphi_{\tau,\upsilon}\circ\varphi_{\sigma,\tau}$, $\varphi_{\sigma,\sigma}=\mathrm{Id}$.

My question is: is **this** statement true? Deligne seems to be asserting these can be made to come from homeomorphisms. On the other hand, they cannot be made to come from analytic isomorphisms. For example, take any elliptic curve $E$ over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ with irrational $j$-invariant; there will be embeddings such that $E\times_\sigma\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{C}$ and $E\times_\tau\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{C}$ are not analytically isomorphic.

Edit: [Crossposting a slightly weaker question on Math Overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/402441/does-the-homotopy-type-of-a-variety-depend-on-an-embedding-into-c).

Comment: A question which feels like it should have the same resolution is: if $X$ is a variety over a field $K\subseteq\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$, then $\operatorname{Gal}\left(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/K\right)$ acts on $H^*_{\mathrm{et}}\left(X,\mathbb{Q}_\ell\right)=H^*\left(X_{\mathbb{C}},\mathbb{Q}\right)\otimes\mathbb{Q}_\ell$. Is this action $\mathbb{Q}$-rational, and can it be described "purely in analytic/singular terms?"

Comment: The action is usually not discrete, thus not $\mathbb{Q}$-rational, so this I find to be cause to doubt the original statement.

Answer (score 1):

To repeat: the OP is misreading the text; $\iota$ is not "an automorphism" of $\mathbb{C}$ but the automorphism complex conjugation. When read correctly, the statement is obviously true; as misread it is obviously false, and there is nothing more to be said. So I was just trying to be helpful to the OP. I don't think I deserve to be attacked by the five users, none of whom seem to understand the question or the answer.

To answer the other question: the text was written by Milne (in English) based on the seminar (in French) by Deligne, and read by Deligne before it was published.

[The original post was deleted by five vigilantes: Adam Zalcman, Leucippus, Shailesh, José Carlos Santos, Arctic Char, Jitendra Singh.]